# Block from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, block

I used a framework Objective-C in my Project (Swift). But in the code have a Block, i cannot convert to swift (i'm newbie in swift)
So the code is

```
[self.datePicker setDateHasItemsCallback:^BOOL(NSDate *date) {
    int tmp = (arc4random() % 30)+1;
    return (tmp % 5 == 0);
}];
```

Please help me.
Thank you ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you would use a block in Objective-C, you use a function in Swift. In Objective-C, the argument is a block that takes an NSDate and returns a BOOL:

```
[self.datePicker setDateHasItemsCallback:^BOOL(NSDate *date) {
```

So, in Swift the argument is a function that takes an NSDate and returns a Bool:

```
self.datePicker.setDateHasItemsCallback {
    (date:NSDate) -> Bool in
    return true // fix this up as desired
}
```

Comment: And see my new Swift tutorial if you don't know about anonymous function syntax: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_anonymous_functions